# SQL Order by ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

The following SQL statement selects all customers from the `Customers` table, sorted by columns `Country` and `CustomerName` , but what confused me the result , since the country result is alright 'cause it's `ASC` -By default so it started from A-Z , as well as the `CustomerName` should be ASC , But the result is not ! so it's not ASC , Why ?

[image]

Comment: Are you  using Oracle, or MySQL? Don't tag databases at random, please tag only the one you're trying to run your query on. Thanks.

Comment: Rows ordered correctly. All customers ordered alphabetically withing each country. This is what you asked SQL server to do with 'ORDER BY Country, CustomerName'

Comment: @ADyson Actually I was thinking there is no difference 'cause it's still the basic ! , so I'm new on it , whatever , I will edit it , Thank you .

Comment: @MohammedRizqallah Show your expected results based on your desired sort order.

Comment: @dfundako I got the idea of it , but I just confused between " , " and " AND " operator , I'm wondering if we changed the " , " between Country and CustomerName , that's going to sort the CustomerName only from A-Z , What about the Country ? , suppose I want to sort them separately from A-Z , I mean Country ( A-Z ) and CustomerName (A-Z )  , Is it possible ?

Comment: @MohammedRizqallah If you want all results ordered by CustomerName only, then just `ORDER BY CustomerName`. I don't know what you mean by "sort them separately". Perhaps add an example of the records in the order you want? AND is not a valid operator for sort order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result are indeed ordered correctly. It orders by Country first, THEN it orders by CustomerName. Within Argentina, your Customers are sorted correctly. Within Brazil, they are sorted correctly.

If you expected Comercio Miniero to be second in the list, ask yourself how that would impact your Country sort order. The sort order will do all the first column, then within that existing order, it will do the second column you listed.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting is fine, and does what it's supposed to.

It sorts by country **and then by** customer. The customers **are** in order... **within each country**.

Look more carefully at the result. Within Argentina the customers are in order, and also within Brazil etc.

How precisely would you expect it to sort by both columns at once anyway? The data in the sorted columns would cease to match to data from the same row. e.g. "Rancho grande" would have to be somewhere near the bottom, instead of next to "Argentina", which it belongs with.

What you appear to be expecting to happen makes no sense, logically.

Answer (score 0):

The results shown appear to be in the order specified.

```
  ORDER BY Country, CustomerName
```

specifies that the rows will be ordered first by the value of `Country`.  And the results appear to be correctly ordered:  Argentina, Austria, Belgium, Brazil.

For rows that have the same value of `Country`, the rows will also be ordered by the value of `CustomerName`.

Again, each set of rows with the same value of Country appears to be ordered correctly, for example, for For Brazil,  `C...`, `F...` and `G...`

---

If we specified  `ORDER BY CustomerName`, then we would get the rows in a different order. With the sample data, with no values of `CustomerName` repeated, then it we could add other expressions to the `ORDER BY` and those would have no effect on the order of the rows.

Comment: @MohammedRizqallah... the expression  `Country AND CustomerName` will be evaluated (to integer value of 0 for all of the example data shown ).  To see that, we can include the expression in the SELECT list. `SELECT Country AND CustomerName AS expr, Country, CustomerName FROM ...`  Since the expression evaluates to zero for all of the rows, then the rows can be returned in *any* order and satisfy the condition `ORDER BY 0`

Answer (score 0):

The results displayed in image are correct. As the query specifies `ORDER BY Country, CustomerName`  then it is following order that it is first sorting according to Country name and for each Country, Customers are sorted in ascending order.